Calculating the integral of $\int_{5}^{8}\left(x-8\right)\cdot\ln\left(x-4\right)dx$
I try to calculate this integral: $\int_{5}^{8}\left(x-8\right)\cdot\ln\left(x-4\right)dx$ and the results are different...
One student had a result of $12.43$ and I had a result of $41.52$. However,WolframAlpha and Desmos show me clearly that the answer is $\frac{33}{4}-\ln(65536)$ which also equals: $-2.84035$...
Could anyone suggest what we did wrong? We only used at the beginning an integration by parts and then proceed forward.
Here are attached images that include our methods:



I would always advise using exact results. In this case, $\frac{33}{4}-\ln(65536)$, not $-2.84035...$ or whatever. Otherwise, you could sometimes have a completely wrong answer that coincidentally looks similar for the first few digits.

The first image seems to claim first
$$ \frac{x^2}{2} - 8x = \frac 12 x (x-8) $$
and then
$$ \frac{x^2}{2} - 8x = \frac 12 x (x-4) $$
Both are incorrect. The second image actually contains the correct one,
$$ \frac{x^2}{2} - 8x = \frac 12 x (x-16) $$
The second image has a correct antiderivative,
$$ F(x) = \frac{x(x-16) \ln(x-4)}{2} - \frac 12 \left(\frac{(x-4)^2}{2} - 8 (x-4) - 48 \ln (x-4) \right) $$
so something must have gone wrong after that.
Working it out, $F(8) = -8 \ln 4 + 12$ and $F(5) = \frac{15}{4}$. Finally,
$$ \int_5^8 (x-8) \ln(x-4)\, dx = F(8)-F(5) = \frac{33}{4} - 16 \ln 2 \approx -2.84 $$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_5^8(x-8) \cdot \ln (x-4) d x 
= & \frac{1}{2} \int_5^8 \ln (x-4) d\left[(x-8)^2\right] \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\left[(x-8)^2 \ln (x-4)\right]_5^8-\frac{1}{2} \int_5^8 \frac{(x-8)^2}{x-4} d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{2} \int_5^8\left(x-12+\frac{16}{x-4}\right) d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{(x-12)^2}{2}+16 \ln |x-4|\right]_5^8 \\
= & -\frac{1}{2}\left(8+16 \ln 4-\frac{49}{2}\right) \\
= & \frac{33}{4}-16 \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$
